# get facebook username name in android app

Tags: android, facebook

I am integrating facebook login an my android app
I have successfully logged in to facebook from app and after success I am opening one activity.

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

          //  String fbname = profile.getName();
            //AppLog.Log("name",);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ComputerCategoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
```

Now I want to send username of facebook profile. For that, if I remove comment from above code and tries to get it by this line:

```
String fbname = profile.getName();
```

I am logging into fb but app is not opening activity So it is going into `onSuccess()` method. Please help why I can't use `Profile.getCurrentProfile();`

Comment: actually it is not crashing but not opening specified activity which means onSuccess() is not executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get it by this way too:

```
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                    // user.optString("name"));
                    // user.optString("id"));
                    // user.optString("email"));                        
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
```

To get profile pic in bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap getFacebookProfilePicture(String userID){
    URL imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: it worked. One more question: How to get profilepicture url ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, in onSuccess method-

```
   final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(
                                                JSONObject object,
                                                GraphResponse response) {

                                            Log.d("Response", response.getJSONObject().toString());

                                            if (response.getError() != null) {
                                                // handle error
                                                System.out.println("Error from FB ");

                                            } else {
                                                try {

    //                                                JSONObject _jObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                                                    if (response.getJSONObject().toString() != null) {                                                    
                                                        if (response.getJSONObject().has("name")) {
                                                            String _facebookName = response.getJSONObject().getString("name");



                                                        }



                                                    }

                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    System.out.println("JSON Error");
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }


                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
```